A rational section with no poles is regular
This is exercise 14.3.F from Vakil's FOAG:

Suppose $s$ is a nonzero rational section of an invertible sheaf on a locally Noetherian normal scheme. Show that if $s$ has no poles, then $s$ is regular. (Hint: Exercise 13.5.I.).

Here is my attempt:
Let $\mathscr{L}$ be the invertible sheaf on $X$ with $\{U_i\}$ an affine cover of $X$ on which $\mathscr{L}$ is trivialized with $\phi_i: \mathscr{O}_X|_{U_i}\to \mathscr{L}_{U_i}$ the isomorphisms. Say $s \in \mathscr{L}(V)$ with $V\neq \emptyset$ then let $\tilde{f}_i = \phi_i^{-1}(s|_{U_i\cap V}) \in \mathscr{O}_X(U_i\cap V)$ since $s$ has no poles, $\tilde{f}_i$ has no poles on $U_i$ so $\exists f_i \in \mathscr{O}_X(U_i)$ with $f_i|_{V\cap U_i} = \tilde{f}_i$. My guess is that we take $s_i = \phi_i(f_i) \in \mathscr{L}(U_i)$ and then show $s_i|_{U_i\cap U_j} = s_j|_{U_i\cap U_j}$ to conclude $\exists s' \in \mathscr{L}(X)$ with $s'|_{V} = s$ but I am struggling to conclude $s_i|_{U_i\cap U_j} = s_j|_{U_i\cap U_j}$.
I would appreciate any suggestions to get the above equality or another approach.

Exercise 13.5.I reads as follows:

If $f$ is a nonzero rational function on a locally Noetherian normal scheme, and $f$ has no poles, show that $f$ is regular.

In your situation, cover your scheme with connected opens $U_i$ where $\mathcal{L}|_{U_i}\cong\mathcal{O}_{U_i}$. Now on each such open, $s$ gives a rational function with no poles, so $s$ actually yields a regular function on each $U_i$. Now these automatically glue together as a regular section of $\mathcal{L}$, since if $U_i$ and $U_i$ both belong to a connected component with generic point $\eta$, we have the maps $\mathcal{L}(U_i) \to \mathcal{L}(U_i\cap U_j)\to\mathcal{L}_\eta$ are injective and the extension of $s$ to $U_i$ certainly restricts to $s_\eta$. (The key facts are that restriction maps on an integral scheme are injective and that a normal locally noetherian connected scheme is integral.)

Thank you! I originally thought I could do this using that the scheme was integral, but didn't think the assumptions implied that. How do we ensure that the $U_i, U_j$ are within one connected component, and which generic point do we use?

A normal locally noetherian scheme has every connected component integral. If $U_i$ and $U_j$ are connected, then they're either in the same connected component, in which case you use the generic point of that component, or they're in different connected components, in which case there's no need to glue. Alternatively, you can reduce to the case of a connected scheme up front, since specifying the section on every connected component is equivalent to specifying the section on the whole scheme by the sheaf property. (Also, is there a reason you didn't upvote this? Was something missing?)

Apologies, forgot to upvote. I have one final question. I can show that a noetherian connected scheme with $O_{X, p}$ integral for all $p\in X$ is integral itself. Is this what you are using to conclude that a normal locally noetherian scheme has connected components that are integral? If so how do we get that the connected components are noetherian and not just locally noetherian? Thank you again!

Pretty sure that connected + all stalks integral + locally noetherian implies integral, but even if that's not the case, you can get around it in this situation: if $X$ is a connected normal locally noetherian scheme and ${U_i}$ is an open cover where $\mathcal{L}|_{U_i}$ is free, then you can subdivide each $U_i$ in to connected affine opens which are notherian and continue on from there: the subdivided schemes are noetherian normal connected schemes which must be integral, so the restriction maps are injective here.
